# What is known about the sandbox used for file parsers in MalwareBytes on Android?

Tags: android, antivirus

Malwarebytes on Android includes a file scanner.  Is it known or claimed to be sandboxed, by anything more than the Android sandbox for the Malwarebytes app?

Or does it avoid using any parser code in languages with low memory safety (C, C++ etc)?

Perhaps they have been independently certified, for protecting their file scanner appropriately?

### Context

File parsers are prone to vulnerabilities.  That's partly why PC antiviruses scan even non-program files.  But it's also why [PC antiviruses have been vulnerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavis_Ormandy), and started to [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) their file parsers.

I have read these previous questions and their answers:

- [Is Android anti-virus software necessary and helpful?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179529/is-android-anti-virus-software-necessary-and-helpful)
- [How do anti-virus apps for Android work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/how-do-anti-virus-apps-for-android-work)